# How to render a collection with a Marionette's ItemView?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js, marionette

I'm trying to render the response from an API (JSON) with `Backbone.Marionette.ItemView`. Not sure why it is not working.

I'm using marionette v2.4.7 (on purpose);

Here is the handlebars template:

```
<script id="feed-post" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each posts}}
    <a href="#"><img src="{{author.image_url}}" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><p>{{author.name}}</p></a>
    <span>TODO TIMESTAMP</span>
    <p>{{body}}</br>{{topic_type}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

Here is my full **app.js** (all Backbone logic in this file);

```
// Model
var Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    authorPic:      'Unknown',
    authorName:     'Unknown',
    timestamp:      'Unknown',
    body:           'Not available',
    comments:       '0'
  }
});

// Collection
var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Post,
  url: 'http://localhost:4321/blogposts',
  initialize: function(){
    this.fetch();
  }
});

// View
var PostView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  el: '#content',
  template: Handlebars.compile($("#feed-post").html()),
});

//Config
var chunkPosts = new Posts();
var myview = new PostView({collection: chunkPosts});
```

Also, I tried to `console.log` the view and it looks like the models are in there.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/wg4NIZr.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This answer is tailored to Marionette v2.4.7. `LayoutView` and `ItemView` were merged and renamed to `View` back in [v3.0.0](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/releases/tag/v3.0.0).*

---

From the [doc on `ItemView`](https://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.7/marionette.itemview.html#rendering-a-collection-in-an-itemview):

> Rendering this view will convert the `someCollection` collection in to
>   the `items` array for your template to use.

You are using `posts` in your template while the doc says it will be called `items`.

As a reference, here's the exact code doing that in the [`ItemView` source](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/v2.4.7/src/item-view.js#L15-L39):

> ```
> // Serialize the model or collection for the view. If a model is
> // found, the view's `serializeModel` is called. If a collection is found,
> // each model in the collection is serialized by calling
> // the view's `serializeCollection` and put into an `items` array in
> // the resulting data. If both are found, defaults to the model.
> // You can override the `serializeData` method in your own view definition,
> // to provide custom serialization for your view's data.
> serializeData: function() {
>   if (!this.model && !this.collection) {
>     return {};
>   }
>
>   var args = [this.model || this.collection];
>   if (arguments.length) {
>     args.push.apply(args, arguments);
>   }
>
>   if (this.model) {
>     return this.serializeModel.apply(this, args);
>   } else {
>     return {
>       items: this.serializeCollection.apply(this, args)
>     };
>   }
> },
> ```

The last lines show that for a collection, a new object with `items` as the only attribute is returned.

It's mentioned that you can override the `serializeData` function, [more information and examples are available in the doc](https://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.7/marionette.itemview.html#itemview-serializedata).

---

You still need to call `render` on the view and since the collection's `fetch` is async, you won't have items out of the box so you should wire a listener.

First, don't fetch in the `initialize` of a collection, it makes the collection pretty much useless for any other use-case.

```
var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Post,
  url: 'http://localhost:4321/blogposts',
});
```

Listen for the collection `sync` event, then fetch within the view instead.

```
var PostView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  el: '#content',
  template: Handlebars.compile($('#feed-post').html()),
  initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
    this.collection.fetch();
  },
});
```

Marionette even offers [`collectionEvents`](https://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.7/marionette.itemview.html#modelevents-and-collectionevents):

```
var PostView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  // ...snip...
  collectionEvents: {
    "sync": "render"
  }
  // ...snip...
});
```

Comment: Hi. I've changed `posts` into `items` but it still doesn't render. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Ah, you are right! It was quite obvious. Thank you, @Emile! xD